# Open Blender maximized by default

Tags: interface, customization

On my PC when I open Blender I always need to manually press maximize button on the window. Is this just something on my PC or is this how Blender starts?

Is there anything I can do so that it's always open maximized?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's controlled based on the window when you save your startup .blend.

To make it default to maximized:

1. Maximize the window.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> Save Startup file*, or File Menu -> Save startup file.

Note that if you make **any**  other changes (not including the splash screen), they will be saved as defaults as well.

Comment: Saving the startup file is not working in windows 8.1. Neither the screen nor the position is saved. I use blender version 2.75.

Comment: Using Windows 10 and Blender 7.7, this does work for me.

Comment: @marts - you're way ahead of the curve man

Comment: I assume he was trying to reply to @christophwerner. Marts, just in case you didn't know, users besides the post authors won't be notified unless you mention them with an @<username>

Comment: worked in Windows 7 & Blender 2.78a. Failed the first round of save/close/restart, but I modified the view (or something else), saved as default, closed, re-opened Blender and voila. May be it saves nothing when changing only the window size. 
Thanks @gandalf3

Answer (score 5):

In windows look for the icon you use to start blender. Right click to bring out the contextual menu, select Properties an in the target path add **-W** at the end.

[image]

Blender will open maximized with no borders.

(for windows 8 go to the start menu, right click on the blender icon and select *Open File Location* That will bring you to the folder where windows stores the shortcut used to open blender. Right click on it to access the properties and edit)

For other options read: https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html?highlight=command%20line#window-options

Comment: Not sure about Windows but for Linux users the -W parameter makes Blender run in Fulscreen mode, which is different than the maximized window, because Blender then covers the whole screen, hiding any system panels and omitting window decoration. Not sure it that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Add an argument to the shortcut.  Note the cases!

> -w

or

> -W

Lower case = start maximized.

Upper case = start fullscreen.  In fullscreen mode, the title bar is hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I found a solution (for Windows 10 at least).  Under the properties for the Blender shortcut, you can go to the "Run" dropdown and pick Maximized.
[image]

Comment: This just maximizes the console window for me.  The main Blender window remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.80 (it's still in Beta but you can get it here: https://builder.blender.org/download/):

- Starts up maximized by default (thanks to https://developer.blender.org/D4332)
- Alternatively you can use a `-M` (or `--window-maximized`) to force it to start maximized (https://developer.blender.org/D4323)

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old, but, since it is - at least for me - the first result for the search "blender star maximized", let me share my solution (windows 10):

First, I did what @gandalf3 said, and saved the start-up file with the window maximized. Still didn't work.

Then, instead of using the desktop shortcut that is automatically created after installation, I actually went to Blender's folder (C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender) and opened Blender.exe directly and voila, it worked.

So I deleted the desktop shortcut and re-created it by right-click dragging "Blender.exe" to the desktop and "Create shortcuts here".

It is very strange, since the new shortcut has the same target as the previous one, but hey, it worked so I'm not complaining.