# Open Blender non-maximized?

Tags: startup-file

Is there a way to tell Blender to NOT open maximized? I want it to open in a normal, non-maximized window.

Windows 10.

Comment: Here you should find your answer, it is the opposite of what you ask: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10820/128477

Comment: No. I don't want to start it full screen or maximized (which are the two things -W/-w does) - I want it to start as a normal window. And, the shortcut is already to start as a "Normal Window" (not maximized or minimized), but it starts maximized. Because, by default, Blender maximizes itself on startup: https://developer.blender.org/D4332